# symbol lookup error(executable problem when linking shared library)

Tags: c, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

The scenario(Linux):

```
   Executable -> shared library -> [xrt static library]
                                   (It is a commercial product based on Motif)
```

The executable will call the shared library, and the shared library will call static library.

I do the following to compile and linking the shared library:

```
$ gcc -fPIC --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-lib -c demo.c      (compling)
$ gcc -shared -o libdemo.so demo.o                                   (linking)
```

**Note here, I do not link the xrt static library though it uses the xrt static library functions**

The executable will link the shared library(libdemo.so) like below:

```
$ gcc -fPIC --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-lib main.c -Ixxxx
$ gcc -o main main.o -Lxxxx -ldemo -L/opt/xrt/lib -lxrtm -lXpm -lxrt3d -lxrtfield -lxrtgauge -lxrtm -lxrttable -lpdsutil
```

**Here the executable linked the xrt static library**

When I run the executable it gives me 'symbol lookup error':

```
$ ./main
./main: symbol lookup error: /xxx/libdemo.so: undefined symbol: xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass
```

In the xrt static library directory, it has some static libraries. And when I run `nm` command, it gives me the below result:

```
$ nm *.a | grep xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass
                  U xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass
0000000000000b18  D xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass
                  U xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass
                  U xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass
```

The `xmXrtTabManagerWidgetClass` symbol is defined in commercial product (which wrapped in static library). Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does `ldd main` output?

Comment: `ldd main` gives me : libdemo.so  (0x.....) and some other stuff. Because the xrt static library is linked into the `main`, they are not shown on the result.

Comment: Makes sense. By any chance do you know if your static library was built using `-fPIC` option? Have a look at this answer, may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41858529/4688321

Comment: I've confirmed that the static library was not built using the `-fPIC` option. Is it a must?

Comment: Not sure really, maybe you can read more about this. I am sure many people have already tried this before.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it seems you need `-fPIC`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53086721/4688321

Comment: Yes, actually it must be linked with `-fPIC`, or else the app will encounter many `symbol lookup error`. Thanks a lot for your help.